# SQL query from single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need query a single table which has following format and expect result as provided. Since status for ID validated and registered are on same day it should be ignored and other ID should be returned

Table 1

```
ID  Status  Date
123 Validated   2/3/2016
123 Registered  2/3/2016
234 Validated   2/5/2016
234 Registered  2/7/2016
345 Validated   2/6/2016
456 Registered  2/9/2016
```

Result

```
ID  Status  Date
234 Registered  2/7/2016
456 Registered  2/9/2016
```

Comment: Please provide the *exact* algorithm you would use to get to the result (i.e., if you write instructions for someone to do it by hand, what would they look like?)

Comment: Eh removed my answer as I see now that there are quite a few variables to this. I think Heinzi is correct, we need more sample data to provide parameters. Can we infer that there is no match in the ID, than you do want to see a Status of Registered, but not Validated?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using a join (with some sample data for testing):

```
create table #table1 (id int, stat varchar(20), dt date)

insert into #table1 values(123 ,'Validated',   '2/3/2016')
insert into #table1 values(123 ,'Registered',  '2/3/2016')
insert into #table1 values(234 ,'Validated',   '2/5/2016')
insert into #table1 values(234 ,'Registered',  '2/7/2016')
insert into #table1 values(345 ,'Validated',   '2/6/2016')
insert into #table1 values(456 ,'Registered',  '2/9/2016')

Select a.*
from #table1 a
left join #table1 b
on a.id = b.id
    and a.dt = b.dt
    and b.stat <> 'Registered'
where a.stat = 'Registered' and b.stat is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(status) over (partition by id, date) as mins,
             max(status) over (partition by id, date) as maxs
      from t
     ) t
where mins = maxs;
```

This returns records that have only one status on each date.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is by a sub query like;

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where Status = 'Registered'
and Date not in (
  select date from tbl
  where Status = 'Validated'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE [Status] = 'Registered'
    AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID, [Date] HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select r.*
from table1 r
left join table1 v
      on v.id = r.id
     and v.[date] = r.[date]
     and v.stat ='Validated'
where r.stat = 'Registered' 
and v.id is null
```

a lot the same as aph +1